# KMeans clustering in Scikit Learn

Tags: python

In k-means in scikit learn , how the initial centroids are selected??
randomly? 
and if I run it several time on the same data , will the accuracy value be changed?
`kmeans =KMeans(data , no of clusters)`

Answer (score 0):

Centroids in the scikit learn implementation can be initialized in three ways:

- WIth `k-means++` for accelerating convergence.
- Randomly
- User defined

In the first case, randomly means (from [k-means++ paper](http://ilpubs.stanford.edu:8090/778/1/2006-13.pdf))

> it is standard practice to choose the initial centers uniformly at random from X .

In the second case, k-means++, also from [k-means++](http://ilpubs.stanford.edu:8090/778/1/2006-13.pdf), they choose centroids as:

> We propose a specific way of choosing centers for the k-means algorithm. In particular, let D(x) denote the shortest distance from a data point to the closest center we have already chosen. Then, we define the following algorithm, which we call k-means++.
>
> - Take one center c1, chosen uniformly at random from X .
> - Take a new center c, choosing x ∈ X with probability D(x) (see reference)
> - Repeat previous step until we have taken k centers altogether.
> - Proceed as with the standard k-means algorithm

And yes, different initializations might end up with different results since the initialization is random and convergence can be found in a local minima.